# Pythonic way of checking null and empty string

Tags: python

I have a simple function that takes 2 params and subtract the first param with the second param.

The function should also do the following:

- Check both params are not null, None or empty string
- Check both params are numeric
- Convert numbers in string into integer (e.g. '7' --> 7)

I am getting errors if empty string is passed in as one of the params. How to write this function in a pythonic way without adding additional checks for empty string?

```py
def get_num_diff(first_num, second_num):
  if ((first_num is not None) & (second_num is not None)):
    if (type(first_num) is str):
      first_num = int(first_num)
    if type(second_num) is str:
      second_num = int(second_num)
    return first_num - second_num
  else:
    return 'NA'
```

Error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: `assert` is what you are looking for.

Comment: `try` and `except` works here too. You never checked for empty string. Also use `isinstance` to check type.

Comment: There is no such thing as "null" in Python. The closest thing is the None object, but you've listed that separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is better handled using try/except rather than building blocks to handle every case you might encounter.

```
def get_num_diff(first_num, second_num):
    try:
        first_num = int(first_num)
        second_num = int(second_num)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return 'NA'
    return first_num - second_num
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense..I was trying to think of ways to capture all cases. This works way better

Answer (score 0):

You can check for an empty string with an if statement.

```
test = ""
if not test:
    print("This test string is empty")

test = "Not Empty"
if test:
    print("This test string is not empty")
```

Below is example output:

```
>>> test = ""
>>> if not test:
...     print("This test string is empty")
... 
This test string is empty
>>> test = "Not Empty"
>>> if test:
...     print("This test string is not empty")
... 
This test string is not empty
```

Comment: Not applicable here since op has numeric values, including possibly 0

Comment: It is applicable if OP decides to use it after they check if what is passed is a string.